# Sending parameter to a Controller

Tags: java, jsf, parameters, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I got this:

```
<a4j:commandLink action="#{searchBean.someMethod}" reRender="search"><span><h:graphicImage value="/home/img/icons/red.gif" width="12" height="12" /> Street</span></a4j:commandLink>
```

And on my Bean, I got a method:

```
public void someMethod(String string){
  doStruff();
}
```

Is it possible to send a String as parameter to my method?

Answer (score 3):

You can send param with `<f:param>` like this

```
<a4j:commandLink action="#{searchBean.someMethod}" reRender="search">
     <span>
         <h:graphicImage value="/home/img/icons/red.gif" width="12" height="12" />Street
     </span>
   <f:param name="stringParam" value="someString" /> 
</a4j:commandLink>
```

and then get it in you method using `ActionEvent`

```
public void someMethod(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    String s = (String) actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("stringParam");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with a4j:actionparam.

```
<a4j:commandLink>
   <a4j:actionparam name="p1" value="hello"/>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

in the bean you only need a getter/setter, you don't need to retrieve the param yourself. a4j:actionparam does the assignment automatically.