# jsf - retrieve parameters from ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf, parameters

How can I add a parameter to an `a4j:commandLink`? The parameter's always null when I check in debug mode.

webcode:

```
<a4j:form>
    <a4j:commandLink reRender="content" action="#{surveyEvaluationBean.doDetailEvaluation}">
        <f:param name="question" value="#{result.question.pK.longValueAsString}" />
        <h:graphicImage url="/survey/img/cloverleaf.jpg" styleClass="srv-analysis-cloverleaf" />
    </a4j:commandLink>
</a4j:form>
```

bean:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    String param = request.getParameter("question");
```

---

I just found the error. There's nothing wrong with the `a4j-components`, the error was the following: I couldn't create the question-object correctly. So the PK was really null. I'm sorry for wasting your time guys.

Comment: what is `result.question.pK.longValueAsString`?

Comment: `result` is the var name of my a4j:repeat and the `getLongValueAsString()`repeats the pk-object as a string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the error. There's nothing wrong with the `a4j-components`, the error was the following: I couldn't create the question-object correctly. So the PK was really null. I'm sorry for wasting your time guys.

Answer (score 1):

1) this should work

```
Map<String,String> params = 
    FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String question = params.get("question");
```

[JSF 2 param example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-param-example/)

2) here another way to achieve it

```
<a4j:commandLink reRender="content" action="#{surveyEvaluationBean.doDetailEvaluation}">
   <a4j:actionparam name="question" value="#{result.question.pK.longValueAsString}"/>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

> in the bean you only need a getter/setter, you don't need to retrieve
>   the param yourself. a4j:actionparam does the assignment automatically. (by Max Katz)

look here [Sending parameter to a Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5109980/617373)

and last one

3) If you use EL 2 and above you can send it as a parameter in `doDetailEvaluation`

like this

```
<a4j:commandLink reRender="content" action="#{surveyEvaluationBean.doDetailEvaluation(result.question.pK.longValueAsString)}"/>
```